# Derived major mode: new keyword fontification not playing nice with parent mode's

Tags: font-lock, derived-mode

I am writing a major mode derived from `f90-mode` in order to fontify the syntax of a commonly used Fortran preprocessor, `fypp` (similar to `jinja2` for HTML templating). Here's a contrived example of what that looks like, with plain `f90-mode` highlighting on the left and my `fypp-mode` on the right.

[image: f90 vs fypp]

The `#:` directive and the `${...}$` evaluator are new syntax atop Fortran, which is why `f90-mode` does not color them properly. I want my major mode to inherit the fontifications defined in `f90-mode.el` and add to them. Here's a minimal but representative implementation

```lisp
;;; fypp-mode.el

(setq fypp-highlights
      '(("#:set" . font-lock-preprocessor-face)
        ("\\${\\|}\\$" . font-lock-preprocessor-face)))

(define-derived-mode fypp-mode f90-mode "fypp"
  "Major mode for editing Fortran code with fypp extensions"
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil fypp-highlights))
```

I have two complaints with this, seen in the right-side image above:

1. The `${...}$` syntax in the subroutine name declaration breaks the fontification of the subroutine name.
2. The `${...}$` inside a string literal does not get fontified, but I would like it to.

Issue #1 I am able to solve by modifying the syntax table entries for `{` and `}` to make them word class instead of parentheses. I do wonder if this is likely to bite me later, though.

Issue #2 is the trickier matter for me. Normally, you want strings fontified as strings, even if they happen to contain keywords. Here, though, the string `"Hello, ${whom}$!"` will get expanded by the preprocessor to `"Hello, world!"`, so I want the `${...}$` to be fontified. I still want string literals to be fontified, I just want my preprocessing tokens to "take precedence". But I don't know how to do this cleanly, if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For issue #1, setting `{` and `}` to word syntax is wrong.  You can give them "symbol constituent" syntax, but not "word" (otherwise you break the expected behavior of `M-f` and friends).  This said, it may indeed bite you later, depending on what the rest of `f90.el` does.

For Issue #2, you simply want to use the *OVERRIDE* field in your font-lock rule.  See `C-h o font-lock-keywords` for details.

Comment: I see, good call on putting curly braces as symbols rather than words (they are not part of Fortran's syntax, so I expect not to step on any landmines.) Also, thanks for pointing out the OVERRIDE field, that's exactly the kind of thing I was searching for!